# if view state is disabled how can I call codebehind function on textbox.textchanged event?

Tags: c#, viewstate

if view state is disabled how can I call codebehind function on textbox.textchanged event?
textbox.textchanged and button click events are not working as view state is disabled

Comment: are you sure it is because of that only ? have you checked it by enabling viewstate ?

Comment: yes , can anyone please tell me other options similar to textbox.textchanged?

Comment: what do you want to do in textchanged event ?

Comment: I have used jQuery function to calcualte total amount but if user has disabled javascript then I need to make sure that function from codebehind needs to get called to calculate total amount

Comment: and is it requirement to disable viewstate ?

Comment: yes my company has done it

Comment: Why you need to check changed textbox for this case? Just always recalculate total value amount on every postback. Ant after that you may compare calculated amount value with value from textbox if you need to show some alert.